# Mysql get count of unique id that repeat in database

Tags: mysql, unique, rows, counting

let say I have the following table:

```
#hotel_id   #room_id     #price    
3             4           50.00    
3             5           45.00    
3             6           50.00    
4             5           45.00    
4             7           50.00    
4             8           45.00    
5             4           45.00    
5             8           50.00    
5             9           45.00
```

what query must I execute in order to get the number of unique #hotel_id - in this case it is 3,4,5 = 3 unique ids
May sound simple , but... :) thank you in advance

########### my query

```
select 
    Count(Distinct a.id),
    rta.room_type_id,
    IF(SUM(price = 0), 0, SUM(price))
from
    adverts a,
    rooms_to_adverts rta,
    room_types rt,
    prices_adverts pa
where
    a.town = 'Sofia' and a.id = pa.advert_id
        and rta.room_type_id = rt.id
        and pa.room_type_id = rta.room_type_id
        and rta.advert_id = a.id
        and (pa.date >= '2013-09-20'
        AND pa.date < '2013-09-23')
        and rt.occupants >= '1'
GROUP BY a.id , rta.room_type_id
order by a.id , rt.occupants ASC
```

this query ouputs this
[image]

LOOKS like it is not so simple :)

Comment: Which is the relation between the table and the query? The table looks pretty simple but the query not.

Comment: the query draws this table, i just changed the table lables above in order to be more understandable, but after all I just need the count of total unique hotel_id ..

Comment: Then the question is bad formulated. You have not such a table but a query's output. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - me - WRONG :) still is there solution for this hard situation ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Part of what you already have is the answer:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT adverts.id)
FROM adverts
```

Or is there a complication that you haven't told us about?

Comment: no, everything is on the table.. that part isn't work - it count how many times mysql met the specific id but it doesnt count total count of unique a.id ...

Comment: Please have a look at the added screenshot to see what query outputs